# Unable to use SCSS with Storybook after building Angular Library

Tags: css, angular, sass, storybook

I'm working on a project where we've built an Angular library using Angular CLI.

We're using Storybook to test the components. I'm a storybook noob but have found it relatively simple to setup. However, I'm struggling to get the scss to compile into css. So when testing my button in question, it is not rendering the correct css.

I have included the following file as per the Storybook docs:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**For further context**
I'm building an Angular library, so that means no appplication. 
To test the Library's components, I'm using Storybook and SCSS.

Has anybody seen this type of issue before? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to anyone who had a look at this.

We figured it out in the end. We were using an enum in our button component file:

*Initially had it like this:*

```js
enum ButtonStyle {
  primary
  
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it was assigning the value of 0 to primary.  The enum was being rendered as it's int value by storybook, rather than stringifying it like angular would. So SASS was compiling fine, it just wasn't compiling what we were expecting.

*Changed it to this:*

```js
enum ButtonStyle {
  primary = "primary"
  
}
```